# Process command line without WMI

Tags: powershell

I've a trouble to read command line of specified process directly from PEB with PowerShell. I'm getting PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION data with NtQueryInformationProcess.

```
# $proc - process handle
if ($NtQueryInformationProcess(
  $proc, 0, $PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION, [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SizeOf(
    $PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION
  ), [IntPtr]::Zero
))) -eq 0) {
  # pointer to RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS
  $ptr = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReadIntPtr($PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION.PebBaseAddress, 0x10)
  # pointer to CommandLine field of structure above
  $ptr = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReadIntPtr($ptr, 0x40)
  # how to get CommandLine field (UNICODE_STRING structure)?
}
```

All pointers is correct but I do not have any idea how to read CommandLine field with Marshal type. Any ideas?

Comment: This sample doesn't feel complete. And what is `$NtQuerInformationProcess`? `$` is for variables while `()` is for methods?

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: If you haven't answer on question then do not post, please.

Comment: This is a comment, it's what they are made to do. Your sample is still not Complete and atm. the question deserves to be closed (code not reproducable). You should make it easy for StackOverflow-users to help you.

Comment: Forget. I'll solve this problem by myself.

Comment: If you don't like my answer, then wait for someone else to answer. I'm just saying that as long as the sample isn't ready to be run, it will take longer for people to help you because they need invest 10min just to get the sample running so they can start debugging. You already have this and could save them that time. We don't know everything by heart and like to verify answers before posting them.

Answer (score 1):

Even though the title says "without WMI", I would still recommend WMI as it's far easier to use. Ex. by using the `Win32_Process` WMI-class.

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Process -Filter "ProcessID = '10708'" | Format-List ProcessID, Name, Path, Commandline

ProcessID   : 10708
Name        : powershell.exe
Path        : C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
Commandline : "C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -version 2
```

Comment: There is in caption: **without WMI**. **I know** how to find CommandLine of process with WMI, but I want to get same result with WinAPI.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice it. I can't understand why you would want WinAPI when WMI can simplify it for you. WMI is also available both locally and remotely (if needed). If you don't want the overhead of WMI, then you should avoid PowerShell too and use a compiled language.

Comment: At firstly, I do not see a fundamental difference which language to use.

Comment: If performance in ms is important (which I would guess based on your choice for complicated WinAPI vs easy WMI), then you will loose much time on the .NET framework loading and compilation of the commands +++ at excecution time which PowerShell does

Comment: Sorry, but if you really think so, you lousy specialist.

Comment: No reason to be rude and I have never called myself a specialist. I'm trying to give my recommendation which I believe is a more suitable solution for your problem and you have yet to give me a reason why a WinAPI solution would be better (I'm actually interested because I might learn something new).